# NUnit & Probing Paths

Tags: nunit

Note: All assemblies here are **not** strong-named

I'm using NUnit (tried 2.4.2 and 2.5.2) to run tests in assembly A. Assembly A references assembly B v2. Assembly A also references assembly C, which in turn references assembly B v1.

When I run assembly A from a bin\Debug directory that only contains assembly B v2, the tests fail with a message about how assembly B v1 can't be found.

I try to solve this by creating an assemblyA.dll.config file. In the file, I specify a binding redirect (even though I know they don't apply to non strong-named assemblies) and a probing path that should allow NUnit to just use assembly B v2.

Unfortunately, I keep getting the same error.

I've also tried using FusionLogViewer to examine the binding process.

```
Assembly Binder Log Entry  (8/19/2009 @ 4:54:38 PM) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  D:\svncheckout\gl\ext\win32\sourceforge\nunit-net20\2.5.2\nunit.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = ????
LOG: DisplayName = assemblyB, Version=1.0.3511.15236, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = .../bin/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = Tests_1523525484
Calling assembly : assemblyC, Version=1.0.0.64031, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file:...\bin\Debug\assemblyA.dll.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from ...\bin\Debug\assemblyB.dll. (this is v2)
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum, I have the following question: I thought that when dealing with non strong-named assemblies, the CLR loads and uses any available version. See this [page from Expert C++/CLI](http://books.google.com/books?id=wZoQyVi5f60C&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=weakly+named+assembly&source=bl&ots=Ef-Vf5Fbvy&sig=FETDkeWO9dCjCuyK3iZ1ofmiKbg&hl=en&ei=LMSMSvbHEonulAeyrci7CA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5#v=onepage&q=weakly%20named%20assembly&f=false). If that's true, why is NUnit complaining about being unable to locate assembly B v1 in the first place? Does this have something to do with the fact that NUnit creates a separate AppDomain in which to run the tests?